# How to pass ListView position to OnMenuItemClickListener

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

I cannot find a way to pass my `position` from `onButtonClick` to my `onMenuItemClick`.
I would like to avoid passing it to class parameter.
Is there a elegant way to do it?

**CODE**

This is how my code looks like now. As you can see I did try to pass it via Tag and receive it from customized parent. But I do not have ability to get to them from `item`.

```
 @Override
 public void onButtonClick(int position, View view, int buttonId) {
            HistoryElement historyElement = historyListAdapter.getElements().get(position);
            if (view.getId() == R.id.hl_button_menu) {
                NeoPopupMenu popupMenu = new NeoPopupMenu(HistoryActivity.this, view);
                popupMenu.setPassedPosition(position);
                view.setTag(position);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItemClickListener);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.show();
            }
 }

 private PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener menuItemClickListener = new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_delete) {
             //NEED POSITION HERE
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: have you tried `popupMenu.setIntent` and `item.getIntent()`?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no I did not, how can I pass my position with it ?

Comment: did you try calling item.getMenuInfo() ?

Comment: prepare an intent as `Intent intent=new Intent();intent.putExtra("position",position); popupMenu.setIntent(intent);` and in `onMenuItemClick` get position from  `intent.getIntExtra("position",0);`

Comment: @pskink I did try like that `NeoPopupMenu popupMenu = (NeoPopupMenu)item.getMenuInfo();` and all I get is nullpointer on popupMenu when calling its methods.

Comment: try to Log.d `item.getMenuInfo()` what do you see in the logcat?

Comment: if both methods are in the same class, then what could be more elegant, than defining a private classwide variable?

Comment: also why dont you use registerForContextMenu(), onCreateContextMenu() and onContextItemSelected()?

Comment: @pskink how that going to change anything? these also have `MenuItem` as argments.

@ρяσѕρєяK You cannot set `Intent` on `PopupMenu` =/

Comment: in your case what item.getMenuInfo() returns? null? when using with ContextMenu it will return AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo which have the fields: long id, int position and View targetView

Comment: @pskink yes it returns null

Comment: more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html

Answer (score 2):

```
private class MyOnMenuItemClickListener implements OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private int position;
    public MyOnMenuItemClickListener(int position){
        this.position = position;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_delete) {
          //use position here
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyOnMenuItemClickListener(position));
```

Comment: Creating new Listener on every single item click call is not the best solution.

Comment: @JakubW if you dont want to use ContextMenu which works "out of the box" (no need for creating, showing etc) but want to use PopupMenu then add this in your NeoPopupMenu constructor: setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); and pass additional position param in new NeoPopupMenu(HistoryActivity.this, view, position);